# Select the children class to instantiate based on a keyword, in python

Tags: python, oop

I want to select a class amongst different children classes, depending on a keyword contained in an input dictionary.
The dictionaries look like:

```
{"car_name": "TeslaS", "electric_engine_name":"X8", "color": "red"}
```

or:

```
{"car_name": "JaguarXE", "gas_engine_name":"V12", "color": "blue"}
```

And my classes look like this:

```
class MotherCarClass(object):
    motor_keyword = None
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(MotherCarClass, self).__init__(*args)


class ElectricCar(MotherCarClass):
    motor_keyword = "electric_engine_name"
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(ElectricCar, self).__init__(*args)


class GasCar(MotherCarClass):
    motor_keyword = "gas_engine_name"
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(GasCar, self).__init__(*args)


car_classes = [
    ElectricCar,
    GasCar,
]

def get_car_class_object_from_dict(car_dict):
    """ find the right child class and return an object
    """
    motor_keywords_dict = {car_class.motor_keyword: car_class 
                           for car_class in car_classes}
    for motor_keyword in motor_keywords_dict:
        if motor_keyword in car_dict:
            return motor_keywords_dict[motor_keyword]()
```

I feel that this pattern is not optimal, does anyone know a more pythonic or Object-Oriented way to do the same thing? Thanks!

Comment: are you literally doing these car classes, or are these euphamisms?

Comment: @Wayne these are placeholders... by the way, the classes are only a way to code different behaviors, and it could be done differently, only the input dictionary is given at the beginning.

Comment: Can the key/values in the dictionary be defined, or are you limited to having different keys in the dictionary signify that you want different behaviors?

Comment: @Wayne no it can't be changed.

Comment: Is it legit to translate/normalize the dict first? If you did that you *could* use dict access to get your class to build with - otherwise I'd probably roll with my example of `if/elif`.

Comment: Yes, it would be a solution, but I wondered if there was a good way to use OOP and heritage directly, instead of selecting a class _via_ a dictionary built outside this classes family.

Comment: I've added some further explanation in my answer, but when it comes down to it, inheritance has nothing to do with how the class is instantiated, just how it's used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)/Factory pattern:

```
def build_car(car_info):
    if car_info.get('electric_engine_name') is not None:
        return ElectricCar(**car_info)
    elif car_info.get('gas_engine_name') is not None:
        return InternalCombustionCar(**car_info)
```

You use the Builder or Factory patterns when you, as the caller *do not care what class instance is returned*, and also should not be concerned with precisely where the class dependencies come from.

In this particular example, you just want a car. You aren't particularly worried *where* the car comes from, only that it has the features you want. So if you want a car with an electric engine, you provide `{'electric_engine_name': 'X8'}`. You're not really worried if you get back a `TeslaModelS` or `SomeGuysCustomCar`, or even `SuperCrazyMotorcycle`. As long as it uses the X8. As long as it adhere's to the interface, and has the engine you're interested in.

Of course, maybe to provide you with the best service, this Builder/Factory requires that you give it some other parameters, such as number of wheels, capacity, range, price, etc.

In some cases it can give you sensible defaults, but let you customize it. It all just depends on what makes sense for your particular situation.

Comment: Thanks for the pattern name!

Answer (score -1):

I would add that you should have an additional attribute in you dict to store the type of engine rather than iterating over the key find a coincidence.